# bitwise Logic framing

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, misra

Hi I have one requirement to be done like example first bit of register should be made 0(reset ) and MSB 4 bits need to be made 1 every time.

I can do this in two steps using :

```
int val=0x0f;
val |=0xf0;
val &=~(1<<0);
printf("val is %d\n",val);
```

I am expecting two lines of code to be framed in 1 logic.I am trying but looking for some good logic from experts.
I got one logic like `val = (val |=0xf0) & ~(1<<0);` but cant use this type of logic since some coding standards used are MISRA.
Please can any one give me some better logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `val = (val |=0xf0) & ~(1<<0);` --> `val = (val |0xf0) & ~(1<<0);`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question; if some codings standards don't permit the one-line solution, it can't be done. Why is there a need for a shorter formulation? The presented solution seems to solve the problem well.

Comment: can I have better logic if possible I tried the logic what you gave.Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: You should specify what is wrong in your code, e.g. quote a rule that your code violates, in addition to any other rules that you think are relevant. Simply asking for "better" code is meaningless if you don't define what "better" means.

Comment: "to be framed in 1 logic" What is this supposed to mean? There's nothing called "logic" in C programming. Do you mean expression? Line? **Why eactly would you want to merge this into one expression/line?** The code is readable now, if you merge it into a messy one-liner, it will turn unreadable. And where does MISRA come in? None of this code is MISRA compliant, neither the original code nor the one-liner.

Comment: You haven't addressed the size of `int` here. The 4 MSB bits are not `0xf0` on every platform. In fact, they are `0xf0000000` on most platforms.

Comment: So use `val = val | (((1<<4)-1)<<(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-4-1)) & ~(1<<0)` instead.

Comment: @barakmanos MISRA-C would take care of that. Unfortunately, this code is not MISRA compliant, so there's potential for bugs.

Comment: @Lundin: How exactly would MISRA (whoever that is) change `0xf0`into `0xf0000000`?

Comment: @barakmanos MISRA has a rule that you must always cast the result of `~` to the intended type, to avoid accidental garbage in the most significant bytes.

Comment: @Lundin: I don't see any `~` in `val |=0xf0`.

Comment: @barakmanos Reading your comment twice, I now see that you were referring to some text in the OP's question about the code supposedly setting the MSB. That doesn't make sense indeed. `int` can never be 8 bits.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, I should probably fix that comment a little bit (from "not `0xf0` on every platform" to "not `0xf0` on any platform). Since the question specifies "4 MSB bits", it is either `0xf000` or `0xf00000000`, and I don't see how MISRA can take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely unclear what you mean, so here's some MISRA code review:

- `int` is not MISRA compliant. Use a fixed-width integer type, preferably from `stdint.h`.
- `0x0f` literals like these are not MISRA compliant. All literals need to have an `u` or `U` suffix, even hexadecimal ones.
- `val |=0xf0;` is not MISRA compliant. You aren't allowed to use bit-wise operators on signed types.
- `val &=~(1<<0)` is not MISRA compliant. There is an important MISRA rule stating that the result of the `~` operator must always be cast to the intended type (called underlying type or effective type depending on MISRA version). Furthermore, MISRA does not allow you to use shift operators on signed types.
- `printf` is not MISRA compliant. MISRA doesn't allow `stdio.h` in production code.

Otherwise, the code is readable and clear. Apart from the fact that `int` is not 8 bits wide, so your talk about setting the MSBs doesn't make any sense.

Naturally, if you try to merge this non-compliant readable code into an unreadable one-liner, it will remain non-compliant. You have to start by making the original code MISRA compliant. Might be wise to actually run it through your static analyser.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned val = whatever();
val = (val | 0xF0u) & ~1u;
```

The nested assignment is unnecessary. I don't have a MISRA copy handy, but I think this should pass. The use of unsigned literals and types is because MISRA disallows bitwise operations on signed integers.

Comment: @Lundin ups.. :D Fixed.

Comment: For MISRA compliance you should use a fixed-width integer type. And then the expression turns more complex, if you suspect that `int` could be larger than that type. The current code dodges multiple MISRA rules just because it contains no implicit conversions.